# bash script run over cron fail some commands

Tags: bash, shell, cron, status

I have a simple bash script to monitor the status of a service.

Script control

- If service its running
- If not running, execute init script start of service and get some lines of log, write a log time of moment and it send email with result.

All working fin except  init script start service when script run on a cron jobs.
If execute manually this script work fine all.

```
#!/bin/bash
estado=$(/etc/init.d/open-xchange status)
echo $estado

if [ "$estado" != "Checking for Open-Xchange: running." ]; then
    hora=$(date +%F-%T)
    tail -n 1000  /var/log/open-xchange/open-xchange.log.0 > /tmp/open-xchange.log.$hora
    cat /tmp/open-xchange.log.$hora |mail -s "Reinicio en OX $hora" xxxxxx@gmail.com
    rm -f /tmp/open-xchange.log.$hora
    echo $hora >> /root/caidas-ox.txt
    /etc/init.d/open-xchange start   # The problem. This command not work when scripts its executed form crond
    sleep 10
    /opt/open-xchange/sbin/showruntimestats -d 'java.util.logging:type=Logging!setLoggerLevel!!ALL!'
fi
```

All commands on conditional working fine on shell and with cron, except **/etc/init.d/open-xchange start** (try using /bin/bash /etc/init.d/open-xchange start, service open-xchange start,...)

Comment: This question seems to be about a particular product, Open-Xchange, right? If it is, then I don't think this a proper general programming question.

Comment: Why are you not using `service`?

Comment: If user service the problem it's same. Since previously try

Comment: Sami Laine, not its' a problem for specific app. Problem its for a execution a command on bash script running with cron. 
If change this specifici app for other the problem it's same. 
Apreciate help, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /opt/open-xchange/lib/oxfunctions.sh: line 109: start-stop-daemon:
>   command not found

start option is calling command `start-stop-daemon` to start the service, any one of 3 options will solve your issue:

1. Find out where is start-stop-daemon, in /etc/init.d/open-xchange,
   replace it with its full path
2. Add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/start-stop-daemon/directory` to your
   script
3. Add `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc` to your script

Answer (score 1):

Your cronjob probably does not have all paths setup. If it works from the command line, do

```
echo $PATH
```

on that command line and add

```
PATH=<...>
```

with `<...>` replaced by the PATH given in the output of the `echo` command. Start your script with

```
<scriptname> 2>/tmp/script.log
```

and check after the cronjob ran to see what goes on.

By the way, to check the status of open-xchange, it seems you could use

```
/etc/init.d/open-xchange status
```

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/open-xchange/sbin/

But a question...
Why work /etc/init.d/open-xchange status and not work /etc/init.d/open-xchange start ??

A lot of thanks for tip to log...
A see a error of path... but I don't understand well your solution.
log show error of path n200  /tmp/xstatus.log
/opt/open-xchange/lib/oxfunctions.sh: line 109: start-stop-daemon: command not found

Comment: `start-stop-daemon` is in `/sbin`. Add the line `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/open-xchange/s‌​bin` to your script.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of thanks @Coroos & @ruifeng

After read your responses, I understand a problem with path on Crontab.

After try several options, the best for me it's add PATH and SHELL variables (same as root user) on top of **bash script**, run with crontab, and work fine.

```
!/bin/sh
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/open-xchange/sbin
```

Work fine

Comment: In that case, please accept one of the answers to show your appreciation for the solution.